# Swagger-Akka-Http: List of objects in the request body

Tags: scala, swagger, akka-http, swagger-akka-http

I'm using [swagger-akka-http](https://github.com/swagger-akka-http/swagger-akka-http) to built Swagger docs for my Akka HTTP service.

My service has a POST method accepting a `List` of `Characteristic`.

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Fetch offerings by characteristics", httpMethod = "POST")
  @ApiImplicitParams(Array(
    new ApiImplicitParam(name = "characteristics", required = true,
      dataTypeClass = classOf[List[Characteristic]], paramType = "body")
  ))
  @ApiResponses(Array(
    new ApiResponse(code = 200, response = classOf[Offering], responseContainer = "List")
  ))
  def fetchOfferings: Route = post {
    entity(as[List[Characteristic]]) { characteristics =>
      // some logic
    }
  }
```

`dataTypeClass = classOf[List[Characteristic]]` in `ApiImplicitParams` is not working as expected. There is the following result in the generated Swagger YAML:

```
 parameters:
   - in: "body"
     name: "body"
     description: "Characteristics"
     required: true
     schema:
       type: "array"
       items:
         type: "object"
```

How can I doccument a collection of objects in the request body?

Comment: why don't  you do it this way case class Characteristics[List[Object]] and give type as Characteristics?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this, to accept a list of objects in the post request.

```
@ApiModel(value = "Request object")
case class Request(
                         @(ApiModelProperty@field)(
                           value = "Name",
                           name = "name",
                           required = true,
                           dataType = "string",
                           example = "DE",
                           allowEmptyValue = false)
                         name: String,
                         @(ApiModelProperty@field)(
                           value = "Marks",
                           name = "marks",
                           required = true,
                           dataType = "List[integer]",
                           example = "[10]",
                           allowEmptyValue = false)
                         marks: List[Int])
```

On your post route you can do something like this.

```
@Path("/student")
  @ApiOperation(
    value = "Returns student information POST request",
    nickname = "getStudentDetails",
    httpMethod = "POST",
    responseContainer = "List",
    code = 200,
    response = classOf[StudentDetails])
  @ApiImplicitParams(Array(
    new ApiImplicitParam(
      name = "body",
      required = true,
      dataType = "Request",
      paramType = "body")
  ))
```